# Local vs Shared Storage for MS SQL Server's Always On Availability Groups: What's Required?

Tags: sql-server, storage, vmware, availability-groups

Is it a requirement for MS SQL Server's Always On Availability Groups to always utilize shared Storage SAN or a virtual shared storage like Storage Spaces Direct? Can I set up Always On Availability Groups using only the local SSDs, HDDs, or even virtual disks of my VMware Virtual Machine without shared storage, while running on a standard Windows Server? I'm planning to use this setup with the MS SQL Server Enterprise Edition. Any insights would be greatly appreciated. ->Planning a HA/DR MS SQL Server Environment on VMware Virtual Machines

Planning a HA/DR MS SQL Server Environment on VMware Virtual Machines

Comment: A windows failover cluster uses shared storage, with Availability Groups normally each server in the AG has dedicated storage that mirrors the primary.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I set up Always On Availability Groups using only the local SSDs, HDDs, or even virtual disks of my VMware Virtual Machine without shared storage, while running on a standard Windows Server?

Yes.  Absolutely.  Not requiring shared disks is a major advantage of Availability Groups compared to Failover Cluster Instances.